# Correctly return variable from python module

Tags: python

I'm sure this is absurdly simple but I have been unable to get it working.

I want to return the value of `x` from within my function `test` in the module 'user_module' to my 'main_program'

**file: user_module**

```
def test ():
    x =5
    return x
```

**file: main_program**

```
import user_module
user_module.test()
print x
```

However the above code does not work :( I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `x` is defined in a function, which means it is in the function's scope, not in the module's. But your function is returning it — which is good:). So use one of these solutions to get `x`:

**1.**

```
import user_module
print user_module.test()
```

**2.**

If you want to pass `x` from one module to another, then your `user_module` will look like this:

```
x = 5
```

and in the main script you do this:

```
import user_module
print user_module.x
```

**3.**

Or you can do this in your `user_module`:

```
def test():
    x = 5
    return x

x = test()
```

Now in your main script you do this:

```
import user_module
print user_module.x
```

Answer (score 8):

In your module x is defined within the function test.
That means that it is only availavle inside the scope of that function.
Even if you would try to access x from within the module you would get a name error because x was not globally defined in that module.

This would **not** work:
file: user_module

```
 def test ():
     x =5
     return x

 print x
```

Produces a NameError.
(that does not mean the general solution is making everything globally available...)

To solve your problem you could create a variable named x.
You would have to change your code like this:

```
 import user_module
 x = user_module.test()
 print x
```

Or instead of printing x you could just print the result of test().

```
 print user_module.test()
```