# Python - If I create a variable inside a function, how can I then use it outside the function?

Tags: python, function

I would like to create a variable inside a function and then use that variable outside the function. Is there a way to do this? For example:

```
def Function():
    score = 5

Function()

print(score)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: `return` it from the function into another variable.

Comment: return `score` and then print your function call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly return variable from python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752512/correctly-return-variable-from-python-module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable outside of function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905437/using-a-variable-outside-of-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return it

```
def Function():
    score = 5
    return score

score=Function()

print(score)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159006/discussion-on-answer-by-superstew-python-if-i-create-a-variable-inside-a-funct).

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options (anyone who has more, feel free to contribute):

Method 1. Declare the variable outside of the function, set it inside the function.

```
score = None
def Function():
    global score # This tells the function to use the variable above
    score = 5 

Function()

print(score) # Or "print score" if using a different version of python
```

Method 2. Return the variable and set it using that.

```
def Function():
    score = 5
    return score

print(Function()) # This bypasses the need to declare score outside the function.
# print(score) # This would not do anything useful, as score was never declared in this scope.
```

Method 3. Use an object orientated approach.

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        App.score = 5

App()
print(App.score)
```

Note that in the first method, you need to declare the variable score outside of the function in order for it to work.

Comment: An short explanation on the pros and cons of the different approaches would be helpful.  This is especially true since you list the poorest choice first; here the OP should know that widely adopting the first method would lead to very poorly written code.

Comment: Changing the contents of a container also persists outside a function, e.g. `score_list = [score] def Function() score_list[0] = new_score` will allow the main function to access `new_score` by accessing `score_list[0]`. I suppose if we're being exhaustive, another option would be writing the variable to disk, and then reading it back into memory..

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can use `global` keyword:

```
def Function():
    global score
    score = 5

Function()
print(score)
```

Comment: But it is technically frowned upon to use global variables when they aren't absolutely needed.

Comment: @NendoTaka I did not say it was anything good, but it certainly does what OP asks for

Comment: @tevemandar I agree, but I wanted to note that it isn't best practice in order to prevent someone from getting into bad habits, such as making everything a global variable. It will work though :)